# In ng-multiselect-dropdown model not working

Tags: angular, multi-select

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown #AddRowWHLocation [data]="dispatchToSDObj.dsAddStock.whLocation"
                [placeholder]="'WH Location'" [settings]="AddRowWHLocationSettings"
                [(ngModel)]="dynamicAddRow[i].WarehouseCode"
                (onSelect)="onAddRowWHLocation($event,i)" (onDeSelect)="onAddRowWHLocationDeSelect($event,i)">
 </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

when removing ngModel it works fine

[image]

Comment: Are you using Reactive or Template driven? Would you please add the component code as well?

Comment: I am using angular 6 and ng-multiselect-dropdown package

Comment: bro share your table code as well.